# Java 1.7 runtime error

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am trying to solve problem on this site: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=979. But part of my code throws runtime error:

```
class Main {

static String ReadLn (int maxLg)  // utility function to read from stdin
{
    byte lin[] = new byte [maxLg];
    int lg = 0, car = -1;
    String line = "";

    try
    {
        while (lg < maxLg)
        {
            car = System.in.read();
            if ((car < 0) || (car == '\n')) break;
            lin [lg++] += car;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return (null);
    }

    if ((car < 0) && (lg == 0)) return (null);  // eof
    return (new String (lin, 0, lg));
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Main jollyJumper = new Main();
    jollyJumper.start();
}

public void start(){

    String input;
    while((input = ReadLn(3000)) != null){
        System.out.println(answer(input));
    }
}

public String answer(String line){
    // The error comes from this function !!!
    String[] items = line.split(" ");
    int[] array;
    try {
        array = new int[items.length - 1];
    }
    catch(NegativeArraySizeException e){
        return "Not jolly";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i +1]);
    }
    return "Jolly";

}
}
```

But the judging system wont tell me where is the error and on my computer everything is working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us the stacktrace

Comment: There is not enough code around to tell you where your program is faulty.  And it'll crash easily. Please provide isJolly().

Comment: @user: the online judging system at that site doesn't provide a stacktrace, it literally provides nothing more than the string "Runtime Error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple reason for a crash of this snippet would be an input line containing more than one space in a row. Guard against this by trimming the array and by splitting on a sequence of white space characters.

```
String[] items = line.split("\\s+").trim();
```

As it is, two spaces in a row result in a conversion error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

**Edit** after substantial edit in the Q.

Another error (according to the specs) is using a

```
byte[3000]
```

for reading a line that can contain a count and up to 3000 integers. Even half as many integers are bound to require more than 3000 characters or bytes. Simply use a Scanner.

Finally method `answer` isn't solving the problem. It just converts the numbers but the required processing - checking that consecutive numbers don't differ by more than a limit, all values from 1 to the limit are there - isn't done.